# Converting a compatible JSON object to a STRUCT

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a function in BigQuery to create a typed `STRUCT` from a `JSON` object? Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
with tbl as (
  SELECT
    STRUCT<name STRING, age INT64>("Bob", 20) AS person_as_struct,
    JSON '{"name": "Bob", "age": 20}' AS person_as_json
)
select
  -- STRUCT -> JSON
  TO_JSON(person_as_struct).age

  -- JSON -> STRUCT
  -- ???
  
from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement,  [json_extract_scalar](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/json_functions#json_extract_scalar) can be used which extracts scalar value and returns it as string. You can try the below sample query.

**Query:**

```
WITH
  jack AS (
  SELECT
    '''
  [
      {
        "Source": "Internet Movie Database",
        "Value": "7.8/10"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Rotten Tomatoes",
        "Value": "89%"
      },
      {
        "Source": "Metacritic",
        "Value": "75/100"
      }
  ]
  ''' json )
SELECT
  ARRAY(
  SELECT
    AS STRUCT JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(rec, '$.Source') AS SOURCE, JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(rec, '$.Value') AS Value
  FROM
    t.arr AS rec ) AS Reviews
FROM
  jack,
  UNNEST([STRUCT(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(json) AS arr)]) t
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Sue, but this is the same as the other comment -- it requires hardcoding the field names into the query and cannot be generalized, right?

Comment: Hi @David542, Since there is no direct function available, you can try the solution provided in this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68709560/bigquery-transform-generic-json-to-struct). Let me know if that resolves your issue.